# Sync Facebook Comments between Mobile and Desktop website

Tags: php, html, facebook, mobile, comments

I have 2 versions of my website **Mobile** and **Desktop** with `Facebook Comment Plugin` embedded in it. I want to sync every comment between the 2 websites having same address except for the subdomain like

```
https://www.example.com/contact-us.php
https://m.example.com/contact-us.php
```

I read about `Comment Mirroring` at [Facebook Comments - Synchronization between website and fan page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004894/facebook-comments-synchronization-between-website-and-fan-page) but I don't think this is what I want.

I want to enable my visitors to comment and see same comments on both these versions. Is it possible or not? I mean if someone comment on desktop version website then the comment should be visible on mobile version as well.

I have this code provided by Facebook when embedding Comment Plugin. Where do I have to change to support comment sync

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>
```

And this code on the page I want to show comment block

```
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.example.com/contact-us.php" data-width="950" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Comment: Just point the plugin to the same URL for both versions, not two different URLs.

Comment: @CBroe how? in Facebook Plugin code at my website or facebook developer network?

Comment: In your site, where you embed the plugin.

Comment: Or, specify the `og:url` for both versions the same. That is something you should perhaps do anyway, because otherwise it will also count likes and shares separately.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my question please check because I don't understand where to update my code.

Comment: I just did it. Thanks to you @CBroe I made it. If you could post it as a answer, I would like to award you this bounty.

Comment: Sure, happy to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments made via the comments plugin are not tied to the page that you embed the plugin on, but to the URL you specify in the data-href parameter.

So if you want to have the same comments on the desktop and the mobile version of your site - specify one of those URLs as data-href for *both* versions.

---

Also, you should use the same `og:url` value for both versions; otherwise, like and share counts will get split over those two distinct URLs.

Comment: Although I solved my problem just like you said by keeping the same URL but yet I could not get what is og:url? where it is?

Comment: Part of the [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup); it is used to tell Facebook what the “real” URL for a piece of content is supposed to be. If you don’t specify it, or specify different URLs for the mobile and the desktop version, then Facebook will count likes and shares separately for those two.

Comment: Thanks CBroe! I have accepted your answer and rewarded you my bounty. Thanks for your kind help.